# How to use AssetManager filter for Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use [AssetManager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager) module with Zend Framework 2.

I have a problem with using filter. At the moment I can combine css files with following  (in module.config.php):

```
'resolver_configs' => array(
    'collections' => array(
        'css/combined.css' => array(
            'css/a.css',
            'css/b.css'
        ),
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../public'
        ),
    ),
),
```

The problem is I cannot minify a css file with following:

```
'filters' => array(
    'css/combined.css' => array(
        array(
            'filter' => 'UglifyCss'
        ),
    ),
),
```

I have also tried CssMin filter, but it doesn't minify either.

There is the documentation about [filter](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager/wiki/Filters), and the filter does not work out of the box and it needs to provide dependencies. If the filters like UglifyCss and CssMin need dependencies, then how do I know what dependencies are needed and how do I provide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filters don't work on collections. They can only be applied to individual assets. If you wish to minify a stylesheet collection you'll have to minify the individual components inside of the collection.

Considering the following configuration:

```
'resolver_configs' => array(
    'collections' => array(
        'css/combined.css' => array(
            'css/a.css',
            'css/b.css'
        ),
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../public'
        ),
    ),
),
```

You'll need these filters:

```
'filters' => array(
    'css/a.css' => array(
        array(
            'filter' => 'UglifyCss'
        ),
    ),
    'css/b.css' => array(
        array(
            'filter' => 'UglifyCss'
        ),
    ),
),
```

As to supplying the dependencies for filters, you can look inside of the filters themselves. They usually contain a link to the required file(s): https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/JSMinFilter.php#L21